# Why do you need a space between the object and method when creating widgets in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm not new to python, but I am just learning the Tkinter module. I've been watching/reading some tutorials and I have come across this more than a few times. In this code, I have created the button, "butt", and want to place it into a grid. The tutorial I followed instantiated the button and at the end of the line, placed a space between the object (button) and the method (.grid()). For the life of me I don't understand why this works.

I went back to make sure that wasn't just an optional syntax similar to how variable = 'data' is equivalent to variable='data', but I have not found anything.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Useful Program")
Button(window, text="butt", width="4") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

The code runs fine. It creates my window with the button in the correct location, but I don't know why the method is running or if it even technically is a method because its from another module.

Answer (score 0):

From python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html?highlight=white%20space)

> White space is only meaningful to separate tokens.

So the white space before the dot is valid (although not common).